# Warning : Apache catalina startup ClassLoaderFactory validateFile

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

A permission issue has been shown in the catalina log.

> Oct 12, 2016 11:52:04 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile WARNING:
>   Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/server/classes], exists:
>   [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]

**Server Information**

> Tomcat Version : Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 (Ubuntu)
>
> JVM Version : 1.7.0_111-b01
>
> JVM Vendor : Oracle Corporation
>
> OS Name : Linux
>
> OS Version : 3.19.0-25-generic
>
> OS Architecture : amd64
>
> Hostname : MyHost
>
> IP Address : 127.0.1.1

**Java**

> java version "1.8.0_101"
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)
>
> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java 1072 manual mode

**Javac**

> javac 1.8.0_101
>
> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javac 1072 manual mode

How can I fix this?

Comment: s there any issue with that warning which says that file/folder doesnt exist

Comment: The message says: the file does not exist, is not a directory and cant be read. Try: "sudo chmod u+rw /usr/share/tomcat7/ -R"

Comment: Thanks, Updated the permission of /usr/share/tomcat7